# How to obtain adjusted font size from UILabel when adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is YES in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, nsstring, uikit, uilabel, textkit

I have a label that is set to `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES` and I need to get the actual displayed font size.

Now iOS 7 deprecated all methods that worked previously and all questions on SO suggest using these deprecated methods.

I will make this question a bounty as soon as I am allowed to by SO. Please do not close.

Comment: The problem is discussed here and has answers!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396715/how-to-figure-out-the-font-size-of-a-uilabel-when-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth-is

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32567240/1442541

Comment: please check my answer at the bottom below

Answer (score 0):

UILabel displayed fontSize in case of using adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth in iOS 7

```c
UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
label.text = @" Your Text goes here into this label";
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:label.attributedText];
// Get the theoretical font-size
[attrStr setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font} range:NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length)];

NSStringDrawingContext *context = [NSStringDrawingContext new];
context.minimumScaleFactor = label.minimumScaleFactor;
[attrStr boundingRectWithSize:label.frame.size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:context];
CGFloat theoreticalFontSize = label.font.pointSize * context.actualScaleFactor;

NSLog(@"theoreticalFontSize: %f",theoreticalFontSize);
NSLog(@"AttributedString Width: %f", [attrStr size].width);
double scaleFactor=label.frame.size.width/([attrStr size].width);
double displayedFontSize=theoreticalFontSize*scaleFactor;
NSLog(@"Actual displayed Font Size: %f",displayedFontSize);

// Verification of Result
double verification=(displayedFontSize * [attrStr length]);
NSLog(@"Should be equal to %0.5f: %0.5f ", [attrStr size].width/17.0, label.frame.size.width/displayedFontSize);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try inserting `[lblObj sizeToFit]` just before requesting the font size

Answer (score -2):

There's a readonly property that lets you do that. You can access it like this

```
nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

//Make sure to use the line below AFTER the line above

float fontSize = nameLabel.font.xHeight;
```

This will give you the font size after it has been adjusted to fit width.

Comment: -1 This answer is incorrect. Have a look at this blog: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/02/understanding-uifont/ —xHeight and all the other metrics of UIFont still only reflect the original font size.

Answer (score -2):

You can get the font size of `UILabel` **text** using these line of code.

```
UILabel *lblObj = [[UILabel alloc]init];
lblObj.text = @" Your Text";
lblObj.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
float size = lblObj.font.pointSize; //Here You will get the actual size of the text.
float lineHeight = lblObj.font.lineHeight;
```

Try this one.

Comment: On iOS 8, `float size = lblObj.font.pointSize` gives me the requested font size, not the actual displayed font size.