# Listen for font reductions on iOS

Tags: ios

When you use `UILabel`, you can set [adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth) along with the appropriate scale factor.

How can I get notified when it scales down? My use-case is that when one label down-sizes, I would like to do it for others around it for uniformity.

Comment: This would make a good enhancement request: http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Some hacky answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284063/how-do-i-get-auto-adjusted-font-size-in-ios-7-0-or-later Don't use any of them.

Comment: thanks matt; enhancement bug -  #25811290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no observation mechanism, you'd need to calculate the size required to fit the text in the available space and use that size on all.

The alternative is to use autolayout to allow the text to wrap and then it doesn't need to scale down.