# When do adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth or boundingRectWithSize change the context.actualScaleFactor?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, font-size, drawingcontext

When does the actualScaleFactor of an NSStringDrawingContext change?

[The documentation says:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSStringDrawingContext_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSStringDrawingContext/minimumScaleFactor)

"If you specified a custom value in the minimumScaleFactor property, when drawing is complete, this property contains the actual scale factor value that was used to draw the string."

**My code:**

```
myButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter-Bold", size: 40)
myButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
myButton.setTitle("\(textString)", forState: .Normal)

let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName : myButton.titleLabel!.font]
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:textString, attributes:attributes)

let context = NSStringDrawingContext()
context.minimumScaleFactor = myButton.titleLabel!.minimumScaleFactor

print("context: \(context.actualScaleFactor)")

let resultingRect = attributedString.boundingRectWithSize(myButton.titleLabel!.bounds.size, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: context)

print("actual context after drawing: \(context.actualScaleFactor)")

//want to get the font size after adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth has done its magic:      
//let actualFontSize = myButton.titleLabel!.font.pointSize * context.actualScaleFactor
```

Console log for both text that fits without being shrunk and longer text that is adjusted to fit the label's width are both the same:

```
context: 0.0
actual context after drawing: 1.0
```

Any idea what step I am missing to get a real scaleFactor from context after the text has been sized to fit the label?

Comment: Thank you for translating to swift.  It works fine for me.  I have a UILabel with actual font size 70pt, minimum scale factor 0.1, and "adjustsToFit" set to true.  When executing your code AFTER viewDidAppear, my console output showed: "context: 0.0
actual context after drawing: 0.36
adjustedFontSize: 14.4".  And indeed when I applied this adjustedFontSize to my label's font (after setting "adjustsToFit" to false), changing the text does not change the font size.

Comment: Most likely this answer will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58340894/9024807

Answer (score 0):

do this in viewDidAppear... That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The same problem as @RanLearns.

After add `myButton.titleLabel!.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1` it worked for me