# Adjust UILabel font size without .adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have two UILabels which I need to adjust the font size in order to properly fit the text (namely in smaller, older devices).

This would be easily solved with the `.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property but the thing is that, as both `UILabels` are near one another and convey similar information, I want them to have the same font size (and `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` will adjust them independently).

So, what I was thinking to do would be to, somehow (this is where I need help) calculate what would the font size need to be for both the labels and use the smallest on both.

[image]

Any ideas on how to do this? Both labels are multiline (2 lines) and they always have the same size.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post a screenshot.

Comment: Do you know on forehand which of the two will need the smallest font? that would make it easier

Comment: @AdilSoomro here it is http://imgur.com/a/5KShO

Comment: @Eric I'm going to give the user the chance to customize the screen so I won't be able to know which one will be bigger :/

Comment: okey, I changed my answer, it should compile now

Answer (score 0):

What you could do have the .adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property true, get font of smallest one, then compare the two widths and set the width of both to the smallest one. Example in pseudo code:

```
.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
var fontSizeOne = labelOne.fontSize
var fontSizeTwo = labelTwo.fontSize

if(fontSizeOne < fontSizeTwo)
  {
    labelTwo.fontSize = labelOne.fontSize
  }
else
  {
    labelOne.fontSize = labelTwo.fontSize
  }
```

Comment: Initially I thought of this but it looks like that the fontSize property remains the same despite any change to the font size!

Answer (score 0):

You could make @Will's answer ever shorter using the `min` function:

```
    labelOne.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true 
    labelTwo.adjustFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    var fontSizeOne = labelOne.font.pointSize
    var fontSizeTwo = labelTwo.font.pointSize

    var min = min(fontSizeOne, fontSizeTwo)
    labelOne.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: min))
    labelTwo.font = labelOne.font
```

Comment: 1st of all thanks for the reply Eric! However this didn't work. As I suspected the pointSize remains the same despite the visual change of the size.

Comment: fontSizeOne: 20.0
fontSizeTwo: 20.0

Comment: It seems to be very hard to get the actual font size, maybe [this stack-overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622503/when-do-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth-or-boundingrectwithsize-change-the-context-act) can help you?